# Mock multiple calls of a class function

Tags: python-3.x, mocking

I have an issue with mocking multiple calls of a class function. My goal is to raise an Exception on a second function call. What's happening is that mocked function returns just a mocked object, without calling it. So in a result on first function call it returns just a function.

First example:

```
with mock.patch.object(FunctionClass, "function_to_mock") as mocked_function:
    mocked_function.side_effect = [mock.DEFAULT, Exception()]
```

Second example:

```
original_function = FunctionClass.function_to_mock # to store reference to the original function 
with mock.patch.object(FunctionClass, "function_to_mock") as mocked_function:
    mocked_function.side_effect = [original_function, Exception()]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with writing:

```
def _is_exception(obj):
    return (
        isinstance(obj, BaseException) or
        isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, BaseException)
    )


class MultipleSideEffectsMock:
    def __init__(self, side_effects_collection):
        self.side_effects_collection = side_effects_collection

    def side_effects(self, *args, **kwargs):
        side_effect = self.side_effects_collection.pop()
        if callable(side_effect):
            return side_effect(*args, **kwargs)
        elif _is_exception(side_effect):
            raise side_effect
        return side_effect
```

which can be used as:

```
original_function = FunctionClass.function_to_mock # to store reference to the original function 
with mock.patch.object(FunctionClass, "function_to_mock") as mocked_function:
    mocked_function.side_effect = MultipleSideEffectsMock(side_effects_collection=[Exception(), original_function]).side_effects
```

I'm pretty sure that it could be archived by some cleaner solution or by pure mocks usage, but I didn't have time to investigate it deeper.